# Java spring on weblogic proxy issue: weblogic.net.http.HttpUnauthorizedException: Auth scheme NEGOTIATE is not supported

Tags: java, spring, proxy, weblogic

Java spring on weblogic unable to make http request through company proxy server

Java 1.8.0b65,
Spring 4.2.3,
Weblogic server 12.1.3

This code works fine when https calls go to servers on our company network but when attempting to make the call to an external url (public internet) through the company proxy server, it fails.

We have these JVM args set:

`-Dhttps.proxyHost=our-company-proxy-host.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=81 -Dhttps.proxyUser=a-user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=a-pwd`

Here's the code:

```
        URL url = getURL();
        HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        final byte[] requestBody = getRequestBody();

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + requestBody.length);

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(requestBody);
```

This is the stacktrace:

````
<09-May-2023 11:29:50 o'clock BST> <Error> <Net> <BEA-000903> <Failed to communicate with proxy: our-company-proxy-host.com/81. Will try connection host-server-trying-to-connect-to.com/443 now.
weblogic.net.http.HttpUnauthorizedException: Auth scheme NEGOTIATE is not supported!
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getSchemeAndRealm(HttpURLConnection.java:550)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getProxyBasicCredentials(HttpURLConnection.java:441)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.makeConnectionUsingProxy(HttpsClient.java:477)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.openServer(HttpsClient.java:354)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:566)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace```
````

The exception was thrown on this line:
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

We found removing the proxy user and password correctly gives a 'java.net.ProtocolException: Proxy or Server Authentication Required', also curl from the weblogic box to the destination using the proxy settings works, so we know they are correct.

We also tried manually configuring the Proxy in code as follows, but same exception results:

```
        URL url = getURL();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("our-company-proxy-host.com"), 81));
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                 return (new PasswordAuthentication("a-user",
                        "a-pass".toCharArray()));
            }
        };
        Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator)
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
        HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection(proxy);
        ...
        // remaining code as per previous example
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue it appears was the the autowired proxy config had a preceding space, I failed to include this detail in my code above. For example:

Incorrect:

```
@Value("${proxy.username: a-user}")
private String proxyUser;
@Value("${proxy.pass: a-password}")
private String proxyPass;
```

Corrected:

```
@Value("${proxy.username:a-user}")
private String proxyUser;
@Value("${proxy.pass:a-password}")
private String proxyPass;
```

I don't know why we didn't get a proxy authentication failure, the "Auth scheme NEGOTIATE is not supported!" sent us down a painful rabbit hole! Hopefully this may help others spot a simple mistake.